# How do I control how a Python class is printed (NOT a class instance)

Tags: python

I have a Python class with *class attributes*, and I would like it to show the values of the attributes when printed.

But instead, it just shows the name of the class.

```py
class CONFIG:
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2


print(CONFIG)  # <class '__main__.CONFIG'>
```

Of course, if I wanted to instantiate the class, then I could `def __repr__()` and control how it prints.

The question is, how do I control how a class (NOT a class instance) prints? Is there an equivalent to `__repr__` for the class itself?

Workarounds:

- Write a function that uses `vars()` or `dir()` to iterate over the attributes
- Instantiate the class, stop doing things a weird way :)
- Change my code in some other way so I no longer have the requirement to print the class (use Enum, SimpleNamespace, etc.)

Comment: In Python, everything is an object, including classes. If you want to control the behavior of a class object, you need to implement a *metaclass*, a class of a class. The base metaclass is `type`. All classes are instances of `type`, e.g. `isinstance(int, type)`

Comment: So implement your metaclass, `class MyMeta(type): ...`, e.g. `def __repr__(self): return "Example"` Then specify that your class definition statement that it should use the custom metaclass, `class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta): ...` then `print(MyClass)` should give you `Example`

Comment: [Here is the basic documentation of how this all works](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).